# JSF action listener not called

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I am using `JSF 1.2` and `RichFaces 3.3.3`, and I have a very strange issue, what the code does is take the name of the media item to be searched and put it in the backing bean attribute searcTitle, and when the user clicks the search button the `onSearch` action listener populates the results list.

And here's the code

```
<rich:panelBar>
   <rich:panelBarItem>
       <rich:tabPanel>
           <rich:tab label="Media">
              <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                 <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                   <h:inputText value="#{media.searchTitle}"/>
                   <a4j:commandButton value="Search" actionListener="#{media.onSearch}"/>
                 </h:panelGrid>
                 <a4j:outputPanel id="mediaSearchResults" ajaxRendered="true">
                    <rich:dataTable value="#{media.results}" var="item">
                       <h:column>
                          <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
                       </h:column>
                    </rich:dataTable>
                 </a4j:outputPanel>
              </h:panelGrid>
           </rich:tab>
       </rich:tabPanel>
   </rich:panelBarItem>
</rich:panelBar>
```

And the backing bean code

```
private String searchTitle="";
private List<MediaItem> results;

public void setSearchTitle(String title){
    getLogger().log(Level.INFO,"At the setter of the search title string"); 
    this.searchTitle = title;
}

public String getSearchTitle(){
    return searchTitle;
}
//Setter and getter for the results list;

//Action Listener
public void onSearch(ActionEvent evt){
   getLogger().log(Level.INFO,"At the actionListener"); 
   //Some function that searches and populates the results list
   populateResults();
}
```

Now the problem is whenever I click on the search button, the action listener is never called, although while inspecting the page with fire bug a request is sent to the server everytime I click on it, but the action listener itself is not triggered.

Does anyone have a clue why I'm having this issue? I'm a beginner at this, so please keep your words simple.

Thanks in advance.

Here are the Reposne/ Request headers from firebug

Response Headers

```
Ajax-Response   true
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate, max_age=0, no-store
Content-Type    text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date    Sat, 02 Jun 2012 16:03:13 GMT
Expires 0
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    Servlet/2.5, JSF/1.2
```

Request Headers

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en,ar;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  17986
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  JSESSIONID=de975352b3adc4f59d57006755ea; JSESSIONID=de682f835c0fa928413ba7e5f59d; form:tree-hi=form:tree:applications:enterpriseApplications
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
```

And the link to the xml payload of the response http://justpaste.it/10uh

Comment: Your request contains 2 session cookies. This doesn't look right and might be a possible cause of your problem. Restart the browser or clear the cookies and retry.

Comment: I did try that, and restated the app itself but with no use

Comment: Well, then work through this list of all possible causes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked The possible cause is not visible in the code posted so far. If you can't figure out based on the list, then you'd need to edit your question to include a real SSCCE instead instead of only a partial snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You should try a `f:form` or `a4j:form` around your `a4j:commandButton`.

Comment: I did and still nothing happened

Comment: Can you add the request/response from firebug after triggering the button?

Comment: This are the HTML headers. What about the payload? You will see some XML there.

Comment: This is the HTML content. I'm interested in AJAX response/request after triggering the button ...

Comment: hmm ... no. You find it in Network-All-Response. Everything should be plain text. Something like `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><partial-response><changes> ...`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't seem to find that, this is pretty much all that exists under the request that is triggered right after the command link is clicked.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your concerns